# What are Lua's string.gsub pattern rules?

Tags: replace, lua, gsub

Here is the current script that have running:

```
var_name="[Clan] Imposter"

     while var_name:find("[Clan]")~=nil do 
          var_name=var_name:gsub("[Clan]", "") 
     end

print(var_name)
```

I was expecting `var_name` to be "Imposter" however the result was "[] Imposter".

How do I get the result from this function to be "Imposter"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape square brackets in patterns: `"%[Clan%]"`.